# Coin toss in skiplist - visualizing and finding length and width

Tags: list, linked-list, singly-linked-list, skip-lists

I'm studying for a quiz on lists and arrays and such, and I'm stumped on this last practice question. I was wondering if someone could walk me how to do it? I'm really confused by the whole concept of skiplists and this example below, and I don't know how to draw it or find the length/height like it asks.

[image]